# Using CALL for labels in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, call, subroutine

When using the CALL command to call a label in a batch script, and you end the sub-routine with GOTO:eof, what happens from there? Does it return back to where the sub-routine's CALL is located? Or does it continue on after the location of the call script?

For example:

```
ECHO It's for my college fund.
CALL :OMGSUB
ECHO *runs away and cries like a little girl*

:OMGSUB
ECHO Your mom goes to college.
GOTO:eof

ECHO *picks up jewelry box*
```

After GOTO:eof which line will it echo next?

Comment: See http://www.robvanderwoude.com/goto.php for an example of how to use labels to create "subroutines" and how to exit the batch without repeating those content within the subroutine.

Comment: You could also replace `GOTO:eof` with `exit /b`. Also, `ECHO Your mom goes to college.` will be executed after `ECHO *runs away and cries like a little girl*`, which may not be intended. The solution would be to add an `exit` after `ECHO *runs away and cries like a little girl*`.

Comment: See also [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not just run it and see for yourself? I saved your script to a batch file called foo.bat, and I changed the `Your mom goes to college.` to have an `echo` in front.

```
C:\temp>foo

C:\temp>ECHO It's for my college fund.
It's for my college fund.

C:\temp>CALL :OMGSUB

C:\temp>echo Your mom goes to college.
Your mom goes to college.

C:\temp>GOTO:eof

C:\temp>ECHO *runs away and cries like a little girl*
*runs away and cries like a little girl*

C:\temp>echo Your mom goes to college.
Your mom goes to college.

C:\temp>GOTO:eof

C:\temp>
```

So it's easy to see that after the `OMGSUB` is called, it

1. Goes to the end of file.
2. Then it returns to the line right afer the `CALL :OMGSUB` and echos the "runs away" line
3. Then it echos the Your Mom line again
4. Then it goes to end of file and terminates
5. The line `echo *picks up jewewlry box*` never gets reached.

Comment: because why not ask it in a question, have it get answered, you can get points, people who look it up can find out right away and save some time, and everyone=happy? XD yes I could have easily put it in a batch script but why not just have it documented?  And thank you for the answer. I wasn't sure about that last part, it re-iterating over the subroutine even after it is called.

Comment: Mechaflash, this is trivial to try, actually. I doubt this is a good question that plenty of others will stumble over and be happy to find an answer. But I might be proven wrong.

Comment: You must note that any command placed after a goto will never be executed, like your ECHO *picks up jewelry box*. To avoid these confussions I suggest to never use goto :eof and use exit /b instead.

Comment: C:\>HELP CALL should give you more info.

Answer (score 0):

`GOTO:eof` ends the `OMGSUB` subroutine in your batch file. So `ECHO *runs away and cries like a little girl*` executes next, but `ECHO Your mom goes to college.` will also execute again.

Sidenote which was also a comment:

You could replace `GOTO:eof` with `exit /b`. Also, `ECHO Your mom goes to college.` will be executed after `ECHO *runs away and cries like a little girl*`, which may not be intended. The solution would be to add an `exit` after `ECHO *runs away and cries like a little girl*`.