# Where does GOTO :EOF return to?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to understand where in the code exactly does `GOTO :EOF` return to?

Here is the code:

```
SET count=1 
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN (somefile.txt) DO (call :subroutine "%%G") 
GOTO :EOF

:subroutine  
echo %count%:%1  
set /a count+=1  
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`:EOF` is a predefined label as Microsoft explains in documentation for command [GOTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/goto). The help output by running in a command prompt window `goto /?` explains also this special label for **End Of File**. But this predefined label is supported only with command extensions being enabled as by default.

The help output by running in a command prompt window `call /?` and of course also the documentation for command [CALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call) explain both that `goto :EOF` should be used to exit a subroutine called with `call :Label`.

A subroutine is nothing else than another batch file embedded within current batch file called with command `call`. If the subroutine is at end of the batch file, real end of file marks the end of the subroutine.

But there can be multiple subroutines in a batch file.

So a command is needed for command interpreter to exit the subroutine on reaching a specific line in command processing and go back to the calling command line. `goto :EOF` as well as `exit /B` can be both used everywhere to either exit a subroutine or exit the current batch file processing.

In batch code in question the **first** `goto :EOF` is needed to **exit batch file** processing without an unwanted fall through to the subroutine code after finishing the loop.

The **second** `goto :EOF` in batch code of questioner is for **exiting the subroutine** and continue processing in **FOR** loop in second line. It does not exit processing of the batch file, it exits only the processing of the subroutine.

**Note 1:** `goto EOF` without a colon requires that there is really a line starting with `:EOF` in the batch file, i.e. the label `EOF` must exist in the file. `goto :EOF` always results in exiting subroutine/batch processing with command extensions enabled even if there is a label `EOF` in the batch file because of a line starting with `:EOF`.

**Note 2:** Command [EXIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/exit_2) without parameter `/B` results always in exiting entire command process independent on calling hierarchy and independent on how the Windows command processor was started – with parameter `/K` to **keep** `cmd.exe` running as used when opening a command prompt window or with `/C` to **close** after command processing finished as used on double clicking a batch file. Therefore `exit` without `/B` should be used wisely in a batch file (best: never).

**Note 3:** `exit /B` without or with an exit code works always, but outputs an error message with command extensions disabled as demonstrated by this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableExtensions
echo Use command exit /B with command extensions disabled.
exit /B 5
echo This line is not processed anymore.
```

Executing this batch file from within a command prompt window results in output of the error message:

> The system cannot find the batch label specified - EOF

But the processing of the batch file is exited nevertheless with the exit code value `5` as it can be seen on running next in same command prompt window `echo ERRORLEVEL is: %ERRORLEVEL%` which outputs: `ERRORLEVEL is: 5`

It looks like there is assigned first the specified exit code value `5` to the dynamic variable `ERRORLEVEL` on using `exit /B 5` and next is executed `goto :EOF` because of option `/B`. That fails because of disabled command extensions resulting in the error message and in exiting the batch file processing as it always occurs on a label to go to does not exist in a batch file.

In other words `exit /B` without or with an additional exit code always works, but there should be appended `2>nul` to suppress the error message on command extensions disabled, i.e. use `exit /B 2>nul` (without exit code) or `exit /B 5 2>nul` (with exit code)

**Note 4:** `ERRORLEVEL` is not affected by `goto :EOF`, but the Microsoft [GOTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/goto) documentation is mute on this topic. `exit /B #` sets `ERRORLEVEL` to `#` [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/exit) by Microsoft. `exit /B #` can be also used instead of `goto :EOF` to exit a subroutine with a specific exit code evaluated on the command line calling the subroutine like on using the operators `&&` or `||` or on next command after calling command line with `if errorlevel X`. However, explicitly exiting a batch file or a subroutine with a specific exit code is usually not needed as neither `goto :EOF` nor `exit /B` modify the current value of `ERRORLEVEL`.

**Note 5:** Do not use `goto:EOF` or `call:Label` in a batch file with no space between command **GOTO** respectively **CALL** (argument 0) and the label (argument 1). There should be always used `goto :EOF` and `call :Label` with a space as argument strings separator between command and label. The reason is that `goto:EOF` results in the attempts to find in current directory first a file with name `goto:` and next a file with name `goto:EOF`. The incorrect command `call:Label` results in searching for a file with name `call:` and next with name `call:Label`. The file system returns for both syntactically wrong commands twice to `cmd.exe` that the name is invalid. Then `cmd.exe` detects the colon as reason for the invalid name and splits the command up into command and label argument and finally runs the command with success. The usage of `goto :EOF` and `call :Label` does not cause any wrong file system accesses as `cmd.exe` immediately recognizes the string `goto` respectively `call` as internal command.

For details on `ERRORLEVEL` behavior see:

- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)

Answer (score 8):

`GOTO :EOF` is *functionally equivalent* to `exit /B`, but both forms only works when Extensions are enabled. The test for this point is very simple:

```
setlocal DisableExtensions
goto :EOF
```

Compare previous code vs. this one:

```
setlocal DisableExtensions
exit /B
```

This means that `GOTO :EOF` returns to *the same point* where `exit /B` would return.

Comment: Are extensions enabled by default, or do they have to be explicitly enabled?

Comment: @MaxCascone: The `cmd /?` help screen indicate something like "Command extensions are enabled by default"...

Comment: `goto :eof` returns %ERRORLEVEL% == 1  and `exit /B` as well.

Comment: @Sandburg: No. `goto :eof` nor `exit /B` change the prior %ERRORLEVEL% value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands/34987886#34987886) for further details...

Answer (score 2):

**:eof** means "*End of file*". It's used to make the script finish without executing any of the commands below.

Comment: thanks! but how then does the loop happens? the 2nd GOTO also says :eof  wasn't suppose to say GOTO :DO for example?

Comment: @s6398197atuser `call` spawns a child thread and execution of the current thread pauses until `call` is finished.  `call :subroutine` runs until its own `exit /b` or EOF is reached, at which time execution resumes at the caller.  Leave echo on and you can watch the order in which commands are executed, and hopefully it'll make a little more sense.  [See this page](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) for more information on `call`, and [this page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php) for a tutorial on batch script functions.

Comment: Unclear answer because it will return from a subroutine to a CALL command similar to, say, a "Return" command would return to the calling method in c#. So, it is possible that "the commands below" CAN be executed if those commands are subsequently called as a separate subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

As the `GOTO` and `CALL` are using the same functionality to find a label you have an option to access the `:EOF` with `CALL` too:

```
CALL ::EOF
```

Same as `GOTO` (when `CALL` with the additional semicolon) the actual end-of-file will be the preferable point where the flow of the script will go. If you have your own label\function defined with **EOF** you can access it with single semicolon.

Though calling the `:EOF` has no much use - you can't put a code after the end of file so this line is actually doing nothing (though this will hit the performance as the end of file is parsed). And as `GOTO` and `EXIT /B` this wont work without enabled extensions.